# Help Learning UDK Audio Functionality

Tags: udk

Hi all,

I just got picked up on a project that is using UDK, I'm sound designing, but the project leaders are doing the audio implementation. I want to help out in anyway I can in order to streamline the process by utilizing UDK's audio tool kit to the fullest, unfortunately, I have never working in UDK, only in XNA and FMOD. Are there any good links that can get me up to speed with UDK's audio tool kit?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out: [The Game Audio Tutorial](http://www.thegameaudiotutorial.com/) Its a whole book on game audio within the UDK. You can download the supplied game level for free which will teach you some of the basics.

Comment: Beat me to it Andrew! I've been working through some of The Game Audio Tutorial and can testify to how awesome it is. Well worth purchasing!

Comment: I was turned on to that by a friend as well, thanks guys!

Comment: hey my game audio tutorial book just arrived today too !! 

Answer (score 1):

imho, too much separation between sound creation and implementation limits how audio can be used in a game.  for some games, this doesnt matter - like a game with simple audio requirements (tetris, pacman,...).  BUt most games will benefit from good communication between design and implementation.

dr

Comment: Totally agree. Design and Implementation both go hand in hand together. Quite often either of those depend on the other for a holistic audio experience in games.

Answer (score 0):

There's an FMOD UE3 integration. ([Information about it.](http://www.fmod.org/index.php/products/ue3integration))
I don't know if you'll have the licence to make use of it, but if you do, you might be able to use the FMOD experience you already have to expand what you can do with the UDK.